# Converting sent byte array via socket to string

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

I'm working on small LAN chat application where connection is via 
sockets.

[image: Problem]

As you can see on the image, the original byte Array is badly encoded to string. My guess is that somwhere in connection somewhat happens.

Sending: (Here shuldnt be a problem)

```
           byte[] message = new byte[Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(txtPisanie.Text)];
            message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtPisanie.Text);
            sck.Send(message);
            txtChat.Items.Add("Me: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message));
            txtPisanie.Clear();
```

Async callback:

```
    int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);
            if (size > 0)
            {
                byte[] receiveData = new byte[((byte[])aResult.AsyncState).Length];
                receiveData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
                string receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveData);
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => {
                    txtChat.Items.Add("Friend: " + receivedMessage);
                    Write("Friend: " + receivedMessage);
                }));
            }
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
```

Connection:

```
   epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtIPLocal.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtPortLocal.Text));
            sck.Bind(epLocal);

            epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtIPRemote.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtPortRemote.Text));
            sck.Connect(epRemote);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
```

Initializing sockets:

```
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
```

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Why do you ignore `size` and assume the entire `buffer` contains relevant data?

Comment: can you please add the code how you initialize the socket? thanks.

Comment: The initialization has been added

Answer (score 1):

How many squares do you get?
I think you either send a too large array, where the 'unfilled' bytes are zero, or you create such an array at the receiver side.
 Debug your application! You can use network terminal programs to manually send data via TCP vor UDP.

I suggest Sysinternals TCPView to monitor the connection and the amount of transmitted data, and HWGroup Hercules as network terminal software.